# Different formulas for copper pyrites and bauxite

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, notation, metallurgy

In my book in the chapter on *General Principles and Processes of Isolation of Elements*, I found that the formula for copper pyrites was stated as $\ce{Cu2S.Fe2S3}$ at one place, $\ce{CuFeS2}$ at another place and $\ce{Cu2FeS2}$ at another place.

Are all these taken to be the formula for copper pyrites or are these printing mistakes. I have searched the internet but could not find any useful information regarding this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both $\ce{Cu2S.Fe2S3}$ and $\ce{CuFeS2}$ are the equivalent means to denote [chalcopyrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcopyrite). The first notation, $\ce{Cu2S.Fe2S3}$, commonly used a few decades ago, shows that two sulfides are not just a mechanical mix, but form a chemical compound (same as for crystallohydrates, e.g. $\ce{CuSO4 * 5 H2O}$). The second one, $\ce{CuFeS2}$, is a [formula unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_unit), a more universal and modern representation. Chalcopyrite is a mineral of $\ce{ABX2}$ type, crystallizes in $I\bar{4}2d$ space group.

[image]

**Figure 1.** Unit cell of chalcopyrite $\ce{CuFeS2}$. Color code: $\color{#FFFF30}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{S}$; $\color{#E06633}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Fe}$; $\color{#C88033}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Cu}$.

On the other hand, $\ce{Cu2FeS2}$ is a reduced formula of $\ce{Cu8Fe4S8}$, a superstructured [bornite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornite) [1]. A compound of $\ce{AB2X2}$ type, crystallizes in $F\bar{4}3m$ space group.

[image: Unit cell of superstructured bornite]

**Figure 2.** Unit cell of superstructured bornite $\ce{Cu8Fe4S8}$. Color code: $\color{#FFFF30}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{S}$; $\color{#E06633}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Fe}$; $\color{#C88033}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Cu}$.

Structurally, chalcopyrite and superstructured bornite have very little in common. Unless there is a specific context given, I'd rather say that $\ce{Cu2FeS2}$ is an outlier among the three and is probably a typographic issue. Also, it's not a good practice to mix dot-notated formulas with formula unit representations unless one wants to underline some structural aspects (e.g. molecular assemblies/coordination polyhedra/domains etc.)

#### References

1. Ding, Y.; Veblen, D. R.; Prewitt, C. T. Possible $\ce{Fe/Cu}$ Ordering Schemes in the 2a Superstructure of Bornite ($\ce{Cu5FeS4}$). *American Mineralogist* **2005**, 90 (8–9), 1265–1269. https://doi.org/10.2138/am.2005.1518.

Answer (score 3):

I know of five copper iron sulfide minerals:

[Bornite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornite) - $\ce{Cu5FeS4}$

[Chalcopyrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcopyrite) - $\ce{CuFeS2}$

[Cubanite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubanite) - $\ce{CuFe2S3}$

[Idaite](https://www.mindat.org/min-2002.html) - $\ce{Cu5FeS6}$

[Isocubanite](https://www.mindat.org/min-2052.html) - $\ce{CuFe2S3}$

Comment: Here is some more: talnakhite $\ce{Cu18Fe16S32}$, valleriite $\ce{Cu2Fe4S7}$, fukuchilite $\ce{Cu3FeS8}$, nukundamite $\ce{Cu_{3.39}Fe_{0.61}S4}$, haycockite $\ce{Cu4Fe5S8}$, mooihoekite $\ce{Cu9Fe9S16}$.